# codeigniter, class is not extending from libraries folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is what i did.

My settings in `applications/config/config.php` file

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

Created file `MY_Controller.php` in `application/core`

**MY_Controller.php** file includes:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

created file `Frontend_Controller.php` in `application/libraries`

**Frontend_Controller.php** file includes

```
class Frontend_Controller extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

In last I extended the main contrller class here with Frontend_Controller
my main controller resides in `application/controllers/main.php`

```
class Main extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('PrizeBondSearch_Model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $PrizeBonds = $this->PrizeBondSearch_Model->ShowAllPBS();
        $this->load->view('home', $PrizeBonds);
    }
}
```

**Problem:**
So here comes the problem, when i extend the main controller class with `MY_Controller`, it works perfectly fine,

But when i try to extend the main controller with `Frontend_Controller` class it gives me this below problem

> Fatal error: Class 'Frontend_Controller' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\PrizeBondSearch\application\controllers\main.php
>   on line 3

Any Ideas How to Resolve it?

Comment: Why you put Controller in libraries folder?

Comment: this is exactly the question and answer from tutsplus video tutorial course right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No worries, Found the Solution at Last.

Needed to load the library classname.

So Added the Below lines in the config.php file.

```
function __autoload($classname){
    if(strpos($classname, 'CI_')!==0){
        $file = APPPATH.'libraries/'.$classname.'.php';
        if(file_exists($file)&& is_file($file)){
            @include_once($file);
        }
    }
}
```

It’s working perfectly fine now.

Comment: You should be storing your controllers in `application/controllers`. The libraries directory is not meant for controllers. You solution is bad practice.

Comment: @crypticツ
no i what i am trying to have base controllers. not just controllers.

Answer (score 0):

include Frontend_Controller.php in begining of MY_Controller.php or use spl_autoloader to prevent this error

Answer (score 0):

Some content of the accepted answer are deprecated in PHP.

Use this function instead in your config.php file

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($classname) {
    if (strpos($classname, 'CI_') !== 0) 
    {
        $file = APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $classname . '.php';
        if (file_exists($file) && is_file($file)) 
        {
            @include_once($file);
        }
    }
});
```